# How to add event bubble for calendar in angular with type script

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a calendar and i have to show the events by bubble in angular by using typescript

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

maybe checkout angular material dialog:

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/dialog-from-menu-example.ts

or bootstrap popover:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples

Comment: Actually I took plugin from matcalendar so i wasn't able to edit inside the calendar